# how to know the progress of file downloading

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to download excel using Form && iframe. Excel has been successfully downloaded. The only problem is I can't get the progress of the downloading. I try the onload event of iframe, but when downloading succeeds, the onload event doesn't trigger. So how can I know the progress, or how can I trigger the onload event?

```
<span @click="onDownload">download</span>
<iframe id="id_iframe" name="nm_iframe" style="display:none;" @load="onLoad_iframe"></iframe>
<script>
onLoadframe(){
  let iframe_obj = document.getElementById("id_iframe");
  let pre = iframe_obj.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
  let res = {};
  
  if(pre.length>0){
    res = JSON.parse(pre[0].innerText);
    if(res.code!='0'){
      utils.msg.error(res.message)
    }
  }
},
onDownload(){
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('target', 'nm_iframe');
  form.setAttribute('method', 'get');
  form.setAttribute('action', url);
  document.body.appendChild(form);

  for (var obj in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.tpye = 'hidden';
      input.name = obj;
      input.value = params[obj];
      form.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
  
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);       
},
</script>
```